# Change text in a negative number in Google sheets with apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From an export file I get the following data in a column.
€9,08
€ 8,67-
€6,82
€10,87
€ 7,23-

The negative ones are text and the positive ones are numbers.
I want the text rows to be a negative number.
Can someone help me how I can solve this. Thank you very much for the help.
GJM

Comment: Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you both for your comment. I will do that the next time. Gert-Jan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the column and try to replace with RegExp:

[image]

If you want a script, for the simplest case it could be this:

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  .getRange('A:A')
  .createTextFinder('(.+?)(-)')
  .useRegularExpression(true)
  .replaceAllWith('$2$1');
}
```

It will make the same changes in column 'A'.

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I want to do it with apps script. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: It can be done with script but implementation depends on how the sheet looks like and how you suppose to run the script: from Script Editor? or via custom menu?

Comment: I just added the simplest example of a script that does exactly the same as the Find and Replace tool.

Comment: Thank you very much Yuri,. This is exactely what I was looking for. I do not understand the code but ik works. And perfectly KISS. Keep It Short and Simple. Again, thank you. Gert-Jan

Comment: `(.+?)(-)` this means to find for two groups: (.?+) any symbols and (-) dash at the end. `$2$1` this means put second founded group ($2) at the start and the first founded group ($1) at the end. Good luck.

Comment: Thnx for the explanation Yuri. You have been very helpfull.