# Removing characters from a range using regex in Google App Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am trying to remove all non-digit characters from an extracted range in Google App Script. 
 For example, using the code snippet below, I am able to remove all "A" character from all cells within the range.

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 18, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
range.createTextFinder("A").replaceAllWith("");
```

Now, instead of calling *x* instances of the *.createTextFinder(n).replaceAllWith("");* function, I would like to use regex. 
In particular, the *'\D'* expression would match all non-digit characters, I could then replace them with *""*.
The problem is I have no idea how to apply regex expressions to an entire range ! 
So far I'm assuming it's going to be something similar to the pseudo code below :

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 18, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
var rangeValues = range.getValues();
rangeValues.forEach(//Somehow apply regex here)
```

How would you peole tackle this problem ?

Comment: You have to use `\\D` (two slashes). Example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165115/change-text-in-a-negative-number-in-google-sheets-with-apps-script/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TextFinder accepts regular expressions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder?hl=en#useregularexpressionuseregex):

```
range.createTextFinder(String.raw`\D`) /*https://stackoverflow.com/a/55793086*/
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .replaceAllWith("");
```

Comment: It worked wonders thank you ! Although I had to replace `String.raw`\D`  with `'\\D'` because Google App Script considered these ` characters illegal.

Comment: @DonutsSauvage Are you using the new editor?

Comment: I believe I am yes. It's a small inconvenience and has been easily bypassed though, no need to dig into it too much

Comment: @DonutsSauvage It works for me. I'm sure there are no illegal characters in my code. If you don't want to dig further, that's fine too.